# how to add persistence xml files in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to add spring boot to an existing project that i have. Earlier i had an application context xml file and 4 persistence files along with 3 separate properties files. I used `@ImportResource` feature of spring to import all the files at once in my application class below `@SpringApplication` annotation. The code looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"service","web"})
@ImportResource( { "classpath:applicationContext.xml", "classpath:archive-ticket-persistence.xml", "classpath:rest.properties", "classpath:complete-ticket-persistence.xml", "classpath:datasource.properties", "classpath:ticket-persistence.xml", "classpath:user-persistence.xml" } ) 
        public class Application {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            }
        }
```

I keep getting this error message every single time i run the application

```
2015-08-14 12:46:53.658  INFO 6012 --- [           main] Application                              : Starting Application on squraishi with PID 6012 (C:\Development\newworkspace\Em7Demo\target\classes started by Administrator in C:\Development\newworkspace\Em7Demo)
2015-08-14 12:46:53.721  INFO 6012 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6056677a: startup date [Fri Aug 14 12:46:53 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-08-14 12:46:55.125  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2015-08-14 12:46:55.313  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [archive-ticket-persistence.xml]
2015-08-14 12:46:56.046  WARN 6012 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence]
Offending resource: class path resource [archive-ticket-persistence.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at Application.main(Application.java:12)

2015-08-14 12:46:56.046  INFO 6012 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Development/newworkspace/Em7Demo/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/hostedsolutions/portal/common/1.0-SNAPSHOT/common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.6/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.6/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.2.3.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-core/2.2.3.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.16.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.16.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/atteo/evo-inflector/1.2/evo-inflector-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/json-patch/1.7/json-patch-1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/jackson-coreutils/1.6/jackson-coreutils-1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/msg-simple/1.1/msg-simple-1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/btf/1.2/btf-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.6/aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.6/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.23/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.10.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.7.3.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.9.3.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.jms/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/aopalliance/com.springsource.org.aopalliance/1.0.0/com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.aop/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.asm/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.context/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.expression/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.core/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.transaction/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1/mail-1.4.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.3.2/jsoup-1.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.context.support/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.orm/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.jdbc/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.web.portlet/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.web.servlet/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.web/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.4.0/gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/sourceforge/gwt-widget/gwt-sl/1.0/gwt-sl-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/findbugs/annotations/1.3.2/annotations-1.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-oxm/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-oxm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.6/httpclient-4.3.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/ca/juliusdavies/not-yet-commons-ssl/0.3.11/not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/springframework/org.springframework.test/3.1.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1/c3p0-0.9.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.1/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.1/jackson-core-asl-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.3/httpcore-4.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/commons-pool-1.6.jar]
2015-08-14 12:46:56.062 ERROR 6012 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

so im thinking maybe the files that i added are not getting loaded at all. Am i doing something wrong? Can this be done in a better way? Please guide me as im new to spring boot.

**EDIT:** Adding pom as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>Em7Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Demo</name>
    <description>Demo project using Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: The error message is unambiguous. Most likely, you're mixing different versions of Spring Boot dependencies.

Comment: @chrylis: you want me to add the pom as well as the complete error? its big

Comment: `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` is from Spring Data REST, and I don't see it included anywhere in your POM.

Comment: Have you read the warning by any chance? 
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package. - Move your code in an actual package.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneNicoll i was able to move and that error is not there anymore but it looks like the beans are not getting loaded because i have new error saying that

Comment: I have updated the question with new error @StéphaneNicoll

Answer (score 0):

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">                                                     
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersistenceName" />    
  </bean>

  <jpa:repositories base-package="your.packages.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"  />

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />        
  </bean>
```